# Inductive proof that $2^n $ is bigger or equal to $1+n$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I'm studying proofs by induction and I wonder if what I did constitutes a solid proof or not. I know the three steps to conduct an inductive proof, so I will write down what I did.

Base case: n=1

$2^1\geq 1+1 $ :Correct because 2 equals 2.

Inductive hypothesis: Let n=k
$\implies 2^k\geq 1+k $: assume as true.

Inductive Step: n=k+1

We get that:

$2^{k+1} \geq 1+(k+1)\implies 2^{k+1}\geq k+2.$
Rewriting $2^{k+1}$ we get $2^k.2^1 \geq k+2.$

We know (assumed) that$ 2^k \geq k+1 $ so multiplying both sides by 2 we get:
$2^k.2 \geq 2(k+1)$. Since $2(k+1) $ is larger than $k+2$, we can conclude that $2^k.2\geq k+2$, which is what we wanted to prove in the first place.

Does that hold? I'm specifically doubtful about the multiplication by 2 part. Can I do that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: We can assume $2^n\ge n+1$ and have to show $2^{n+1}\ge n+2$. We can do this as follows : $2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n\ge 2(n+1)=2n+2>n+2$. Your method is also valid. You start with $2^n\ge n+1$ and you are allowed to multiply with $2$, so you can also assume $2^{n+1}\ge 2n+2$. You only have to show $2^{n+1}\ge n+2$, which is obvious because of $2n+2>n+2$. Note : To show $2^n>n+1$, you must begin with $n=2$, since for $n=1$, we have $2^n=n+1$.

Comment: You cannot use the ">" - sign if you only consider the case $n=1$ because for $n=1$, we do not have $2^n>n+1$, so you need another base case. $n=2$ is sufficient, so you can conclude $2^n>n+1$ for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it in detail. I just wanted to know if what I did was ok. And it was! And yea, I know about the > I just dont know how to type the bigger or equal sign.

Comment: OK, then forget my second comment. You can use ">=" , or if you want it more nicely, type "\ge" surrounded with dollar-signs , for example "x\ge 2" , surrounded with dollar-signs, gives $x\ge 2$

Comment: @George learn MathJax here and learn to use it in future usage with this site here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3):

Assume:

$2^{k} \geq 1+k$

Multiply by 2:

$2^{k+1} \geq 2 + 2k > 1 + (k+1)$

Answer (score 1):

This is a
set-theoretic inductive proof .  Let $ P(n) $ be                      $$ 2^n \geq 1 + n $$

and
$$ S = \{ n \in \Bbb N \text{ } | P(n) \text{ is true }\} $$

This is the basis:

$ P(1) $ is true because

$$ 2^1 \geq 1 + 1  = 2 $$

Thus
$$ 1 \in S $$

The inductive proof is now anchored.

Let $  k  $ $\in \Bbb N $ be an arbitrary number.

Assume $ P(k) $ true for $k \in \Bbb N $, the
inductive hypothesis.

Thus
$$ k \in S $$
The induction step is now taken. This is to show:
$ P(k) $ implies $ P(k + 1) $.

Multiply both sides of the expression in $ P(n)$ by 2.

$$ 2*(2^k) \geq 2*(k+1) $$
$$ 2^{k+1} \geq 2*(k+1) = 2k + 2 $$
Note that
$ k \geq 1 \text{ } $ for $ \text{ } k \in  \Bbb N \text{ }$
implies

$$ 2^{k+1} \geq 2k + 2 \geq k + 1 + 2 = k+3 \gt k + 2 = (k + 1) + 1 $$
where
$$ k \geq 1 $$
implies
$$ 2k \geq k+1 $$

Then the expression
$$ 2^{k + 1} \gt (k + 1) + 1 $$

implies $ P(k + 1) $
is true so that:
$$ k+1 \in S $$
Thus $ P(k) $ is true implies $ P(k + 1) $ is true.
The induction
step has now been proven.

So
$$ k \in S $$
implies
$$ (k + 1) \in S $$

which implies (with $ P(1) \text{ }being \text{ } true $ as the basis):
$$ S = \Bbb N $$

and the proof is complete by the Principle of Mathematical Induction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ It's special case $\,a=1\,$ of a Binomial inequality $\,(1\!+\!a)^n\ge 1+na\,$ for $\,n\ge 1$

$\qquad\quad\ (1\!+\!a)^n\ge  1\! +\! na\ $ is true for $\ n = 1\ $ (base),  and the induction step is obvious:

$\qquad\quad\ (1\!+\!a)^{n+1}\! = (1\!+\!a)(1\!+\!a)^n\!\overset{\rm induct}\ge\! (1\!+\!a)(1\!+\!na) =  \underbrace{ 1\!+\!(n\!+\!1)a}_{\large P(n+1)}\  [+\ na^2]$